# How to change slope of a curve in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
x <- c(0,5,10,15,20,24,30,35,40,45,49,54,59,64,69,74,79,85,90,94,100) 
y <- c(0,0,0,0,1,3,5,8,11,16,23,29,37,44,52,59,68,76,84,91,100)
plot(x,y)
```

I would like to be able to change the slope of the curve (Curve 1) by increasing or decreasing it by a given amount, say 50%, so the curve has a similar shape but shallower or steeper slope (Curve 2). I can create a model, but how can I change the slope based on the model?

```
fit <- loess(y ~ x, control=loess.control(surface="direct"))
xn <- seq(0:100)
fitline = predict(fit, newdata=xn)
```

Is there a function in R I can use? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: not entirely clear what you're asking.  if you scale y by a constant you will scale the slope as well.

Comment: Alternately, you could create a parametric model, not just curve-fit with `loess`.

Comment: If you want half the slope, then do `predict(fit, newdata=xn) * 1/2`. If you want 3 times the slope, it's `predict(fit, newdata=xn) * 3`

Comment: I would like to change the values of Y to generate a curve that has a different slope than Curve 1, almost like interpolating towards a curve with a different gradient, like Curve 2. Multiplying by a constant doesn't do it.

Comment: Then you need to be much more specific. For the standard definition of "slope", the slope of a linear best-fit line, multiplying by a constant changes the slope exactly. You're saying that's not what you want, so can you be more specific about what you do want? Maybe draw a picture? Maybe use more precise terms? I don't think fitting a non-parametric model like `loess` will help you, but if you fit a parametric model with a "slope" term (corresponding to the definition of slope you want to use), then you could change that term and simulate new data.

Comment: I'll add that curve 1 and curve 2 look nearly identical to me. I guess Curve 1 starts out a at a lower slope but then gets a steeper slope. They both start at (0,0) and end at (100,100), so  it only the middle you want to change? Do those points need to stay fixed? Maybe some sort of exponential model?

Comment: Gregor, You are right that loess doesn't work because it doesn't fit the lower part of the curve well enough. The way I calculate slope is by simple linear regression *only* of the straight line part of the curve. If I simply multiply the model, the slope changes for the entire curve, which is not exactly what I need. I need it to change in a non-linear manner, the lower part changes at a lower rate than the straight line part, if that makes sense.

Comment: You could try playing with CDFs of the beta distribution for different parameters.  Use `dbeta` and try out paramets with `shape1 > 2` and `shape2 <= 1`. Whatever results you like you could scale to your desired x and y limits.

Comment: Like compare `curve(dbeta(x, shape1 = 3, shape2 = 1), from = 0, to = 1)` to `curve(dbeta(x, shape1 = 3, shape2 = .5), from = 0, to = 1)` to `curve(dbeta(x, shape1 = 10, shape2 = 1), from = 0, to = 1)`

Comment: Gregor, I have used your suggestions. Thank you! I have settled on using the mgcv library, at least for now. It works for my data.